# JQuery: How to change colors dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jumble.js to jumble colors of text, but finding difficulty in dynamically setting the colors from user input.

User selects colors using the spectrum.js color palette. I'm able to strip the rbg from rbg(xxx,xx,xx); to xxx,xx,xx.  but unable to pass that into the jumble call method.

here is my code.

```
 $(document).on('click', '#cypher-branding-jumble-text', function () {
            var colour1 = $("#cypher-branding-jumble-colour1").spectrum("get");
            var colour2 = $("#cypher-branding-jumble-colour2").spectrum("get");

            colour1 = colour1.toRgbString();
            colour1 = colour1.replace('rgb(', '');
            colour1 = colour1.replace(')', '');
            colour1 = colour1.replace(' ', '');

            colour2 = colour2.toRgbString();
            colour2 = colour2.replace('rgb(', '');
            colour2 = colour2.replace(')', '');
            colour2 = colour2.replace(' ', '');

            var colour_1 = [colour1];
            var colour_2 = [colour2];            

            $('#cypher-branding-main-edit-right-txt-text').jumble(colour_1,colour_2,true,false); 
        });
```

Jumble plugin > https://github.com/vonKristoff/jumble

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @Nagappan, I don't get any errors.

Comment: I think this line has to be changed as color_1 = a.split(",") so it will really split into three values and create array. Same for color_2

Comment: @Nagappan I tried did ths > var colour_1 = [colour1.split(",")]; but did not work?

Comment: @Nagappan it worked!! :)   sorry my mistake in previous comment...I was supposed to leave out the square brackets. Thank you!

Comment: Why can't you use Spectrums toRgb() method to get the {"r":255,"g":0,"b":0} value?  You don't even need to parse it?

Comment: @orion I will add this answer, please vote for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read the Spectrum API correctly, this should work with less string nonsense.  And I was able to verify on the Spectrum website that the 'get' call can use toRgb().

```
$(document).on('click', '#cypher-branding-jumble-text', function () {
    var colour1 = $("#cypher-branding-jumble-colour1").spectrum("get").toRgb();
    var colour2 = $("#cypher-branding-jumble-colour2").spectrum("get").toRgb();

    $('#cypher-branding-main-edit-right-txt-text')
    .jumble([colour1.r-0,colour1.g-0,colour1.b-0],[colour2.r-0,colour2.g-0,colour2.b-0],true,false); 
});
```

Why is there a document listener for #cypher-branding-jumble-text, shouldent it just be $('#cypher-branding-jumble-text').click(...)?

Comment: Just tried your method and it worked well..Much better to read with fewer lines.   The listeners part I'm not sure..I have them all wrapped inside $(document).ready(function () {    Is it any different?

Comment: @Orion well if the button doesn't move just link to the button directly.  I typically use the .on() logic when the buttons are moving or dynamic.  For example I would use a $('#table').on('click', 'tr td.actions span.edit'. function(){...}) to allow my dynamic edit buttons to work all the time.

Also you don't need $(document).ready, just write $(function(){...}), and jQuery will handle the ready part for you.

Answer (score 1):

this line has to be changed as color_1 = a.split(",") so it will really split into three values and create array. Same for color_2 also.

Answer (score 0):

Nagappan's comment solved my issue very nicely.

Was meant to split the string.  Modified code as below.

```
$(document).on('click', '#cypher-branding-jumble-text', function () {
            var colour1 = $("#cypher-branding-jumble-colour1").spectrum("get");
            var colour2 = $("#cypher-branding-jumble-colour2").spectrum("get");

            colour1 = colour1.toRgbString();
            colour1 = colour1.replace('rgb(', '');
            colour1 = colour1.replace(')', '');
            colour1 = colour1.replace(' ', '');

            colour2 = colour2.toRgbString();
            colour2 = colour2.replace('rgb(', '');
            colour2 = colour2.replace(')', '');
            colour2 = colour2.replace(' ', '');

            //modified lines using split
            var colour_1 = colour1.split(",");
            var colour_2 = colour2.split(",");

            $('#cypher-branding-main-edit-right-txt-text').jumble(colour_1,colour_2,true,false); 
        });
```